# When should we call base.OnPaint() when we override OnPaint?

Tags: c#, winforms

I am wondering when should we call the base.OnPaint when we override OnPaint in the windows form program?

what I am doing is:

```
  private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            // If there is an image and it has a location, 
            // paint it when the Form is repainted.
            base.OnPaint(e);

        }
```

I get stackoerflowexception, why?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are not overriding the `OnPaint()` method. You are just subscribing to `Paint` event, so you **should not** call `base.OnPaint()`.
You should (could) only call `base.OnPaint()` when you override the `OnPaint()` method of the form:

```
protected override OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnPaint(e);

    // ... other drawing commands
}
```

The `OnPaint` method on Windows Forms controls actually raises the `Paint` event of the control and also draws the control surface. By calling the base form's `OnPaint` method in the `Paint` event handler, you actually are telling the form to call the `Paint` handler again and again, and so you will fall in an infinite loop, and hence the `StackOverflowException`.

When you override the `OnPaint` method of a control, usually you should call the base method, to let the control draw itself and also call the event handlers subscribed to `Paint` event. If you do not call the base method, some control aspects will not be drawn, and no event handler will be called.

Comment: What if you want the Paint event to be raised after the overriding method's "other drawing commands"?

Comment: @mbeckish You can easily call the base method after your own drawings, but the result depends on the type of control and what it does in its `OnPaint` method. You should be aware that the control could paints itself over what you have just drawn on it. Hopefully erasing the background will not happen in `OnPaint` method but in `OnPaintBackground` method.

Answer (score 3):

The `base.OnPaint(e)` method raises the `Paint` event, so your `Form1_Paint` method is called inside `base.OnPaint`. This results in an infinite loop and eventually a `StackOverflowException`.

The correct thing would be to override the `OnPaint` method:

```
protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnPaint(e);
    //custom painting here...
}
```

For more info, see this [MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cksxshce.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

from the code above You're not overriding the OnPaint method, you're actually handling the paint event, and, of course, if you try to paint it again inside the handler you get an infinite loop.